# Bruhathkayosaurus matleyi current status and size estimates

Tags: taxonomy, palaeontology, dinosaurs

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BqVqW9A-6eo

I watched this YouTube video about *Bruhathkayosaurus matleyi* and he basically makes three interesting assertions:

1. The illium used to define *Bruhathkayosaurus matleyi* was not of a sauropod but of a 9 meters abeliosaurid.
2. The huge femur (incorrectly) assigned to *Bruhathkayosaurus matleyi* is indeed a huge sauropod but needs to be defined as a new genus (the author suggests "*Fangorn*").
3. The size estimations coming from the huge femur now lost are valid and suggest a 110-170 metric tonnes animal of length 38-48 meters.

The video is based on a 2023 paper by Gregory S. Paul, a free-lance paleontologist and paleoartist whose hypotheses are often disputed (especially in taxonomy) and are not mainstream.

I ask if these three assertions are accepted by the scientific community? what is the status of the giant sauropod formerly referred to *Bruhathkayosaurus matleyi* and whether is it a valid species? And I ask if the size estimates are widely accepted, making it the largest dinosaur?